# How to get the correct value of / and % operators?

Tags: c, operator-keyword

I want to do the following things:

I use a variable `int a` to keep the input from the console, and then I do the following:

```
int b = a / 16;
```

When `a` is 64 or 32, I get 4 or 2. But if `a` is 63, I expect to get 4, but I get 3. Are there any ways in C to get a rounded value?

**Edit**. More details:

```
rang 1 to 16 should get 1,
rang 17 to 32 should get 2,
rang 33 to 48 should get 3,
rang 49 to 64 should get 4
```

Comment: What is it that you want? `round(a / 16.0)`, round up: `(a + 15)/16`?

Comment: or round to nearest-ties-up `(a + 8)/16)` (for positive `a`)?

Comment: You aren't "suppose" to get 4. You want 4, for some reason, but when you divide 63 toys between 16 kids, each one gets 3.

Comment: @user2131316...What is result if `a = 61,60` ?

Comment: @user2131316... `/16` is fix or it may be change to any number -> `a / 5`,`a / 13`,... ?

Comment: any number, and I added more details in the post

Comment: How would you want to treat negative numbers and 0?

Comment: there should be negative number and 0

Comment: If everything is guaranteed to be positive, `(dividend - 1) / divisor + 1` is the simplest way. (You can write that `(dividend + (divisor - 1)) / divisor` if you prefer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the division operator `/` with two `int` arguments, it will returns an `int` representing the truncated result.

You can get a *rounded-up* division without using floating point numbers, like this :

```
int a;
int den = 16;
int b = (a + den - 1) / den;
```

Which will give you what you expect :

```
a ∈      [0], b =        0 / 16 = 0,
a ∈  [1, 16], b = [16, 31] / 16 = 1,
a ∈ [17, 32], b = [32, 47] / 16 = 2,
a ∈ [33, 48], b = [48, 63] / 16 = 3,
a ∈ [49, 64], b = [64, 79] / 16 = 4,
...
```

Note that this only work if `a` and `b` are positives, and beware of the possible overflow of `a + den`.
If `a + den` is suspected to possibly overflow, then you could use another version of this expression :

```
int b = (a - 1) / den + 1;
```

The only downside is that it will return `1` when `a = 0`. If that's an issue, you can add something like :

```
int b = (a - 1) / den + 1 - !a;
```

Note that you can also handle negative values of `a` the same way (round away from zero) :

```
int b = (a > 0) ? (a - 1) / den + 1 : (a - den + 1) / den;
```

Answer (score 2):

Integer division `/` in C does not do **rouding**, instead, it does **truncation**.

Comment: @user2131316 See Lundin's and praks411's answers for a way to do it using floating-point division and rounding. See my answer for a way to do it using a simple integer division.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
int ans, newNo;
int no = 63; // Given number
int dNo = 16; // Divider

newNo = (no % dNo) ? (dNo - (no % dNo) + no) : no; // Round off number

ans = newNo / dNo;
```

## Edit

**Optimize solution**

`ans = (no / dNo) + !!(no % dNo);`

Comment: You can avoid the branching by writing `ans = no/dNo + !!(no%dNo);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using following

```
 int b = (int)ceil((double)a/16);
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever you are trying is conceptualy not correct but still if you want the same result as you said in your question , you can try for standard function `double ceil(double x)` defined in math.h

Rounds x upward, returning the smallest integral value that is not less than x.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get what you want is to use float numbers.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
  double a = 63.0;
  double b = 16.0;

  printf("%d", (int) round(a / b));

  return 0;
}
```

---

Carefully pay attention when casting from float numbers to int, and vise versa. For example, `round(63/16)` is incorrect. It returns a double, but achieves nothing, since the literals 63 and 16 are integers. The division is done before the value is passed to the function. The correct way is to make sure that one or both operands are of type double: `round(63.0 / 16.0)`

Comment: Simplest way ? Is `(int)round(a/(double)b)` really simpler than `(a+b-1)/b` ?

Comment: Changing a very simple integer solution to a floating point one is not really a good idea. It has a worse performance (floating point operation), it's more error-prone (like you said in the answer) and less portable (not always possible in kernel code, or microcontrollers).

Comment: Also, only a 80-bit `double` can store a 64-bit `int` without losing precision.

Answer (score 0):

Since C int division always rounds towards zero, a simple trick you can use to make it round evenly is to add "0.5" to the number before the rounding occurs. For example, if you want to divide by 32, use

```
x = (a+16)/32;
```

or more generally, for a/b, where a and b are both positive:

```
x = (a+b/2)/b;
```

Unfortunately negative numbers complicate it a bit, because if the result is negative, then you need to subtract 0.5 rather than add it. That's no problem if you already know it will be positive or negative when you're writing the code, but if you to deal with both positive and negative answers it becomes messy. You could do it like this...

```
x = (a+((a/b>0)?1:-1)*(b/2)) / b;
```

but by that stage it's starting to get pretty complex - it's probably better to just cast to float and use the `round` function.

--

[Edit] as zakinster pointed out, although the question asked for 'round' values, the examples given actually require `ceil`. The way to do that with ints would be:

```
x = (a+b-1)/b;
```

again, if the answer can be negative this gets complicated:

```
x = (a+((a/b>0)?1:-1)*(b-1)) / b;
```

I'll leave my original response for even rounding just in case someone is interested.

Comment: He doesn't want to *round*, he wants to *ceil*, see the OP.